Download csv data using python from a website
I'm trying to download csv data from this page https://bancadatistatisticaoas.inail.it/analytics/saw.dll?Portal&PortalPath=%2Fshared%2FBDS%2F_portal%2FINF_Denunciati_totale_gestioni
At the bottom there is the the link "Esporta", then dati and then csv. I'm trying in python with this code but the only thing that I download is an html file. What I'm doing wrong? thanks
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Setup Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\ColameoMarcello\Downloads",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
})

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

try:
    # Navigate to the page
    driver.get("https://bancadatistatisticaoas.inail.it/analytics/saw.dll?Portal&PortalPath=%2Fshared%2FBDS%2F_portal%2FINF_Denunciati_totale_gestioni")

    # Wait for the "Esporta" button and click it
    esporta_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="d:dashboard~p:uiqor2i5pr25913u~r:cadc28dh9ejqrg6oLinks"]/tbody/tr/td/a'))
    )
    esporta_button.click()

    # Wait for the "Dati" button and click it
    dati_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="popupMenuItem"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]'))
    )
    dati_button.click()

    # Wait for the "CSV" button and click it
    csv_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="popupMenuItem"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]'))
    )
    csv_button.click()

    # Wait for the download to finish (adjust time as needed)
    # This is a simple sleep; for a more robust solution, check the download directory for a new file
    import time
    time.sleep(10)

finally:
    # Clean up by closing the browser
    driver.quit()


Did you try chacking here ? https://dati.inail.it/portale/it.html they seem more updated and much easier to collect.

Issues: The XPath locators are incorrect. They are not locating the targeted element. For example, this XPath expression //*[@id="popupMenuItem"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2] locates 10 elements.
Suggestions:

Just create one WebDriverWait object and reuse it, instead of creating it each time while locating element.

Use relative XPaths as in my answer which are easy to read and understand

Don't store the element into a variable if you only want to perform click() once, instead just use click() at the end as soon as you find element


Here is the refactored working code:
# Navigate to the page
driver.get("https://bancadatistatisticaoas.inail.it/analytics/saw.dll?Portal&PortalPath=%2Fshared%2FBDS%2F_portal%2FINF_Denunciati_totale_gestioni")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 90)

# Wait for the "Esporta" button and click it
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'ReportLinkMenu'))).click()

# Wait for the "Dati" button and click it
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='Data']"))).click()

# Wait for the "CSV" button and click it
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='CSV']"))).click()

UPDATE: Answer to second question, check the code below:
driver.get("https://bancadatistatisticaoas.inail.it/analytics/saw.dll?Portal&PortalPath=%2Fshared%2FBDS%2F_portal%2FINF_Denunciati_totale_gestioni")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 90)

# open combobox (Genere)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@title='Genere']//following::input[1]"))).click()
# deselect first one (All Column Values)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@type='checkbox'])[2]"))).click()
# select second one (Femmine)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@type='checkbox'])[3]"))).click()
# Click FILTRA
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Filtra']"))).click()


Which combo box? Can you point me to the element you want to select?

Thanks! Only one last thing. I'm trying to click on "F Costruzioni" from this link https://bancadatistatisticaoas.inail.it/analytics/saw.dll?Dashboard&PortalPath=%2Fshared%2FBDS%2F_portal%2FINF_Denunciati_Industria_e_Servizi
which should be the code? thanks
